# R csv table filtering

Tags: r, csv

I have large CSV file which contain this data:

```
OSversion,device,office,owner
10.3.2,iphone5.2,antwerpen,moti
7.0,samsung_nexus,bangkok,raman
...
```

Then, I have loaded it to the RStudio with:

```
library(readr)
output <- read_csv
```

I'm comlpletely new to R and have no idea where to start.

I would like to filter output table and receive following information.

How much devices with unique OS version?

```
10.3.2 - 405
7.0 - 803
```

How much devices with each OS version in the each of the offices?

```
antwerpen, 10.3.2 - 2
antwerpen, 7.0 - 1
bangkok, 10.3.2 - 3
bangkok, 7.0 - 2
```

Then, portray a devices owners.

```
antwerpen, moti, 10.3.2 - 1
antwerpen, esther, 10.3.2 - 1
antwerpen, esther, 7.0 - 1
bangkok, raman, 10.3.2 - 1
bangkok, ankur, 10.3.2 - 1
bangkok, arjun, 10.3.2 - 1
bangkok, arjun, 7.0 - 1
bangkok, raman, 7.0 - 1
```

And finally, assemble a full list of attributes with device model.

```
antwerpen, moti, 10.3.2, iphone 5.2 - 1
antwerpen, esther, 10.3.2, iphone 6.3 - 1
antwerpen, esther, 7.0, samsung_nexus - 1
bangkok, raman, 10.3.2, ipad 8.2 - 1
bangkok, ankur, 10.3.2, ipad 9.2 - 1
bangkok, arjun, 10.3.2, iphone 5.2- 1
bangkok, arjun, 7.0, samsung_note - 1
bangkok, raman, 7.0, samsung_nexus - 1
```

Could you please assist and point me how to do this or provide me with an example of such filtering?

**UPDATE:**

I have grouped columns as variables by using `group_by` and assigned them as `OSversion` `device` `office` and `owner`. Then, i was able to count unique coincidences by using this command: `summarise(office, u_owner = n_distinct(owner), u_OSversion = n_distinct(OSversion), u_device = n_distinct(device))` but it only counts numbers, without showing an actual values.

Could you please suggest something further?

**UPDATE2:**

Totally resolved by the
`ddply(df, c("office","owner","OSversion","device"), nrow)`
Which count unique values just as it repetition times.

Comment: Most answers can be achieved using dplyr/tidyr (especially group_by and summarise in your case) check: https://monashbioinformaticsplatform.github.io/r-more/topics/tidyverse.html#dplyr

Comment: @timfaber thank you for the useful link!  I have grouped columns as variables by using `group_by` and assigned them as `OSversion` `device` `office` and `owner`. Then, i was able to count unique coincidences by using this command: `summarise(office, u_owner = n_distinct(owner), u_OSversion = n_distinct(OSversion), u_device = n_distinct(device))` but it only counts numbers, without showing an actual values. Could you please suggest something further?

Comment: What values should be represented? Maybe set `summarise(...drop=FALSE)` to retain the rest of the columns

Comment: @timfaber right now its showing me result in this manner, just counting unique matches 
`1  antwerpen     3         5        4`                                                          but i would like to portray it like this:
`antwerpen, moti, 10.3.2, iphone 5.2 - 1`                                                                                   portraying not only numbers of matches but also a corresponding values from the related columns

Comment: If I read the upper example and run the following example (with package: tidyverse loaded) `df %>% group_by(office,owner,OSversion,device) %>% summarise(m=n_distinct(owner))` I get the line you describe.

Comment: @timfaber tried to do so, but it just showing me unique rows, same as the `count_(unique(df), c("office","owner","OSversion","device"))`. Number of repetitions of each unique string is still not portrayed, but it should, since specific `owner` in the particular `owner` could have many devices with matching `OSversion` and `device`

Comment: @timfaber Totally resolved by the 
`ddply(df, c("office","owner","OSversion","device"), nrow)`
Which count unique values just as it repetition times.

Comment: Nice! If I run my code I get the exact same outcome but if it works it works!